# "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: python, django, django-models

"The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

"i am working on exam-app using python django ,but getting error in loginview function while running on localhost,how do i solve this?"

in views.py this the following loginview class where it's showingerror

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'exam/login.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username  = username, password = password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(self.request, user)
        if user.role == 2:
            return redirect("student")
        elif user.role == 3:
            return redirect("index")
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)`
```

error showing is:
    ValueError at /login/

```
The view exam.views.LoginView didn't return an HttpResponse 
object. It returned None instead.
```

user role is set ,please refer to attached file
        `    from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, 
BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):

    if not email or not password:
        raise ValueError("User must have email and password")

    user = self.model(
        email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
        **kwargs
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    user = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.role = 1
    user.save()
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
SUPER_ADMIN = 1
STUDENT = 2
TEACHER = 3
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    (SUPER_ADMIN, 'Super Admin'),
    (TEACHER , 'Teacher'),
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False)
email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
role = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = ROLE_CHOICES, null = True)
objects = UserManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
def get_full_name(self):
    return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
def get_short_name(self):
    return self.first_name

class Section(models.Model):
section = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.section)

class Question(models.Model):
section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.question)

class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question,max_length = 200, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
choice = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.choice) 

class Exam(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
start_date = models.DateTimeField()
duration = models.IntegerField()
section = models.ManyToManyField(Section)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

`

Comment: What if user role is not 2 or 3?

Comment: But note that this code is mostly pointless; AuthenticationForm already authenticates the user, that's the point.

Comment: can you please check again i added models.py file

Comment: You didn't need to post the models. You need to think about what happens if the user role is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return self.form_invalid(form)` for `return super().form_valid(form)` in your `def form_valid(self, form)` function. I think you are calling your own function and not the `FormView` class one. Also add an `else` after:

```
if user.role == 2:
    return redirect("student")
elif user.role == 3:
    return redirect("index")
```

With a redirect function (it can be a `raise Http404`).